# listview output in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

i am trying to make a wifi scanner in wpf, i tried in windows form application and it is working perfectly through c# but i am getting duplicate output of my listview first column in wpf  with the following code

<

```
       <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="100 "/>
                <GridViewColumn Width="100"/>
                <GridViewColumn Width="100"/>
             </GridView>
        </ListView.View>



and code behind
Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork[] networks = wlanInterface.GetAvailableNetworkList(0);
            foreach(Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork network in networks)
            {
                Wlan.Dot11Ssid ssid = network.dot11Ssid;
                string networkname = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ssid.SSID, 0, (int)ssid.SSIDLength);
                System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem item = new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem(networkname);
                item.SubItems.Add(network.dot11DefaultCipherAlgorithm.ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(network.wlanSignalQuality + "%");
                lv1.Items.Add(item);
            [C# winodws form output][1]
```

Comment: Do not add a WinForms ListViewItem to a WPF ListView. WinForms and WPF are different frameworks. Don't mix them.

Comment: if i remoe system.windows.Forms then i am getting this error
Error 1 A using namespace directive can only be applied to namespaces; 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem' is a type not a namespace

Comment: So you wrote `using System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem;`? Besides that you'll get a compiler error, you would still be using WinForms. Write `using System.Windows.Controls;` instead.

Comment: tried using System.Windows.Controls; but still getting error